# Save Design Time Web Page

Tags: save, html

I have a simple question is it possible to save a html which has some changes on it, I'm not talking about code changes. User will come and type some words in textboxes and click some check boxes than user will save the current page and changes will kept.

I'm trying it on internet explorer I have my page I'm typing some words in textbox than when I  do file save as and save and when I reopen it changes won't keep.

Any ideas?

As a follow on, thank you very much for the replies guys I don't know how did I forget about cookies.

Anyways when recheck my project I found out that I want my webpage to be act as a normal document meaning that when users make some changes as I said before inputs to text and etc. I want my users to save these changes and send this 'changed' webpage as an attachment to email. So my main idea is user will do some input to a local page it isn't on server by the way and they will save this page and they will send it.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are client side, it will save data in cache for a particular time, then it will refresh once you reload every time.

Comment: Than I want to save that cached data is it possible I mean can client save their changes on website?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you can use cocckies for that, Save the state of your controls in a cocckie and reload it when page gets reloaded next time,
For more info on cockies [Go here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Second solution for HTML 5 based is `local storage`, for more info on that [Go here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp)